# City golf 1.3 overheating badly

Tags: engine, cooling-system

I bought a new thermostat and heat gauge switch, however, my car is overheating.

Every time I fill it with water, it sucks the water and I have to refill it.

When I switch the car off it over heats but when I drive the water light flicks.

Comment: So you keep refilling?  with just water? any puddles where the car is parked?

Comment: I tried to clean up your question a bit.  Is there any more information you can provide?  What year is your car?  Does it overheat on the freeway?  Did you flush your cooling system?  What do you mean by it, it sucks water?  Thanks, welcome to stack exchange.  Cheers!

Comment: If the coolant isn't leaking out under your car, then you might have head gasket problems. That would be the next thing to check.

Comment: Voting to close, question is unclear and OP is not responding to comments.